# Using redux, why can't I import a json file directly to createSlice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Why does this work:

```
import myData from './data.json';

const initialState = myData;

const wevaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'weva',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
         // whatever
    }
})
```

and this doesn't ?

```
import myData from './data.json';

const wevaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'weva',
    myData,
    reducers: {
         // whatever
    }
})
```

If I try the 2nd option I got the following error:

Uncaught Error: The slice reducer for key "weva" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.

Any ideas why is this? Does this has anything to do with Immer lib? If yes can anyone explain why the 2nd option doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these are not positional arguments.
`initialState` there is a shorthand for

```js
const wevaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'weva',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
         // whatever
    }
})
```

So your second snippet is akin to calling

```js
const wevaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'weva',
    myData: myData,
    reducers: {
         // whatever
    }
})
```

Instead, you can do

```js
const wevaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'weva',
    initialState: myData,
    reducers: {
         // whatever
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes... perfect. Thanks.